# mobile image does not appear in mainpage.xaml

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

[image: mainpage.xaml]

In my mainpage.xaml the windows mobile image(phone page) does not appear, instead white screen appears.How to get the phone page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following forum post seems like a similar issue to yours "How do you set the skin of your design pane?":-

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/45712f01-1e4f-4dec-8896-21933f736336